# Variant float to double value conversion with rounding to 1 decimal place

Tags: c++, winapi, com, double, rounding

I have variant of VT_R4/float type with value "2.550000" when converting it to double using VariantChangeType() to VT_R8/double type value becomes "2.54999999998".

```
::VariantChangeType(&var, &var, 0, VT_BSTR);
::VariantChangeType(&var, &var, 0, VT_R8);
double dOutputValue = var.dblVal;
```

this double when is when rounded of using

```
output.Format(_T("%3.1f"), dOutputValue);
```

gives value 2.5, instead of 2.6 as expected.

Please suggest.

Comment: Google "floating point precision". 2.55 cannot be represented exactly in floating point.

Answer (score 1):

> I have variant of VT_R4/float type with value "2.550000".

No you don't. That value is not exactly representable in a binary floating point type. The [closest single precision value to 2.55](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=2.55) is:

> 2.5499999523162841796875

If you wish to represent 2.55 exactly you will need to use a decimal data type rather than a binary data type.

Comment: Or a rational data type.  Or something else.  There are a lot of possible solutions, but as you say, `float` and `double` aren't among them.  (You might also point out that this comment is "typical": the standard does allow a decimal floating point representation, although the last machine I saw which used such internally was well before the days of C++, or even C.)

Comment: @James The standard in play here is the COM variant data type, VT_R4. That's IEEE754 binary single precision. A rational would do the trick too.

Comment: I want to get 2.6 as output, currently it is giving 2.5 instead.

the same code works well for all other values, execpt mid point value rounding of.

Comment: Please try and understand my answer and realise that your variant does not hold the value 2.55 in a VT_R4 because there is simply no VT_R4 with that exact value.